# How can I hide InitializeComponent in my XML documentation generated with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm using a feature of Visual Studio to generate XML documentation for my custom user controls (Project properties -> Build -> Check "XML documentation file").

This documentation is visible from applications that use these controls, and I would like to only include what is relevant. For this purpose, I put the code in a separate assembly and mark some of my classes, methods and properties as 'internal'.

However, the InitializeComponent method, auto-generated for WPF user controls in C#, is public. I've searched a bit but I'm unable to find a way to make it internal, or to remove if from the XML auto-generated documentation, without some post-build hack, and I'm reluctant to do that.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this small inconvenience?

Comment: No, there's little you can do about it beyond the thing you don't want to do.  The comment is auto-generated, it has no knobs to tweak.  It is rather useless, I'd recommend you file a bug report at connect.microsoft.net

Comment: Thanks. It's more like a missing feature than a bug, I guess they have more on their plate than improving this.